# Check the number of bytes on each line of a file

Tags: command-line

I want to check the number of bytes on each line of a file.

If the number of bytes is not the expected number, then store the record along with its line number in a new file.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
expected=72
<a-file LC_ALL=C grep -nxvE ".{$expected}" >a-new-file
```

Or:

```
<a-file LC_ALL=C awk -v expected=72 '
  length != expected {print FNR, $0}' >a-new-file
```

`length` returns the length without the line delimiter. Beware some `grep`/`awk` implementations would choke on input that contains NUL bytes or very long lines.

GNU `awk` won't and can get the length of the record including the delimiter with:

```
<a-file LC_ALL=C gawk -v expected=73 '
  length($0 RT) != expected {print FNR, $0}' >a-new-file
```

Or you could use `perl`:

```
<a-file perl -nse '
  print "$. $_" unless length($_) == $expected' -- -expected=73 >a-new-file
```

Add the `-l` option if you don't want to take into account the line delimiter. `perl` works with bytes by default regardless of the locale, so you don't need the `LC_ALL=C`.

Comment: Need it using Unix, for loop, if else and grep to be more specific.

Comment: @Anaya, certainly not. [Using shell loops to process text is very bad practice](/q/169716).

Comment: @Anaya please edit your question and explain exactly what you need. Doing this in the shell is a bad idea.